# Unable to install chatterbot using pip

Tags: python, pip, chatbot, chatterbot

I am getting below error when i execute the command pip install chatterbot after step "Installing build dependencies".
Can someone please let me know how I can correct it or is there any other way to install it?

ERROR:

```
Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\suchint\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe' 
'c:\users\suchint\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 
'C:\Users\Suchint\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-dt4dcbfx\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i 
https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'
```

Comment: Is this the full traceback ? Please paste the command you tried to install too

Comment: I have used pip install chatterbot

Comment: Please update whatever happened after you did `pip install chatterbot` including the same in the question :)

Comment: try ``pip3 install chatterbot``

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the same error occurred because of incompatible version of **chatterbot**. 
I tried installing the specific version i.e **1.0.0** of chatterbot and it worked for me.
Use this command to install the same :

```
pip install chatterbot==1.0.0
```

I referred this video too: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tSjR7bk1Y9U

Answer (score 1):

run

```
sudo apt-get update
```

then run

```
pip install chatterbot
```

if that does not work

run:

```
git clone https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot.git
```

go into the folder just created and run:

```
pip install ./ChatterBot
```

Comment: Didn't worked I tried downloading the files from git and tried installing it using command pip install ./chatterbot but still got the same error. :(

Answer (score 1):

**A Special Case if your Python version is above 3.3**

It is just to Python's incompatibility with few plugins on which `chatterbot` is dependent.

Like if you do

`pip install chatterbot==1.0.4`

You will end up in `collections.Hashable` error if Your Python version is above 3.3

The `collections.Hashable` error is caused by the use of an attribute that has been deprecated since Python 3.3 (which was released around a decade ago).
The chatterbot includes PyYAML version `3.12`. The latest version is `6.0`.

The solution in such case is unfortunately downgrading unless you change core file inside pyyaml

Goto `lib\site-packages\yaml\constructor.py` in python folder and change: `collections.Hashable` to `collections.abc.Hashable`

Answer (score 0):

The chatterbot-corpus is distributed in its own Python package

Install

```
pip3 install chatterBot-corpus
```

Python & ChatterBot Version conflicts, So error occurs, chatterbot-corpus is used to avoid further issues.

Comment: explain what `-corpus` in your command helps solving the issue OP addresses; this will rid yourself from the "low-quality" answer labeling. (End of Review).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it using the previous version of chatterbot:
`pip install chatterbot==1.0.4`
Look at this thread for more information: https://www.bountysource.com/issues/83146413-pip-install-chatterbot-error

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install chatterbot, you should use

```
pip install chatterbot --no-binary :all:
```

Make sure to run the following three commands before installing it.

```
conda remove --force PyYAML
pip install pint
pip install mathparse
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating pip:

```
pip install --upgrade pip
```

And *then try again*:

```
pip install chatterbot
```